# Dataframe to dictionary collecting specific values

Tags: pandas

I have the following data:

```
                       repeat  num_samples    score
dim num_centers noise                              
2   2           0.1       9.5       1000.0  0.99875
                0.2       9.5       1000.0  0.97695
                0.5       9.5       1000.0  0.95210
                1.0       9.5       1000.0  0.75535
                2.0       9.5       1000.0  0.67500
                5.0       9.5       1000.0  0.57735
                10.0      9.5       1000.0  0.56395
                100.0     9.5       1000.0  0.55320
    3           0.1       9.5       1000.0  0.99125
                0.2       9.5       1000.0  0.95110
                0.5       9.5       1000.0  0.81915
                1.0       9.5       1000.0  0.69520
                2.0       9.5       1000.0  0.51390
                5.0       9.5       1000.0  0.43085
                10.0      9.5       1000.0  0.40255
                100.0     9.5       1000.0  0.39430
3   2           0.1       9.5       1000.0  0.99990
                0.2       9.5       1000.0  0.99790
                0.5       9.5       1000.0  0.96915
                1.0       9.5       1000.0  0.86350
                2.0       9.5       1000.0  0.74360
                5.0       9.5       1000.0  0.61485
                10.0      9.5       1000.0  0.58160
                100.0     9.5       1000.0  0.57370
    3           0.1       9.5       1000.0  0.99995
                0.2       9.5       1000.0  0.98755
                0.5       9.5       1000.0  0.92930
                1.0       9.5       1000.0  0.73040
                2.0       9.5       1000.0  0.59975
                5.0       9.5       1000.0  0.46510
                10.0      9.5       1000.0  0.43385
                100.0     9.5       1000.0  0.42865
```

I would like to have a dictionary with 4 keys:

```
dim=2, num_centers=2
dim=2, num_centers=3
dim=3, num_centers=2
dim=3, num_centers=3
```

and the corresponding values are the 2D numpy array with the `noise` and `score` columns.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can have a list of values but not separate values as a dictionary does not suport duplicate keys, so you can have 2 keys `2` and `3`

Comment: but I need the tuples... The tuples (2,2) (2,3) (3,2) (3,3) are possible...

Comment: It looks like you have a multiindex, in which case calling`df.index` would return what you want? Apologize if I didn't understand your question. Please explain more in that case

Answer (score 0):

"Plain" call to *to_dict* will not get the required value,
because index values are not unique.

To generate your result, run:

```
result = { key: grp.values for key, grp in df
    .reset_index(level=2).drop(columns=['repeat', 'num_samples'])
    .groupby(level=[0,1]) }
```

Then e.g. execute *result[(2,2)]* (actually print this value)
and you will get:

```
array([[  0.1    ,   0.99875],
       [  0.2    ,   0.97695],
       [  0.5    ,   0.9521 ],
       [  1.     ,   0.75535],
       [  2.     ,   0.675  ],
       [  5.     ,   0.57735],
       [ 10.     ,   0.56395],
       [100.     ,   0.5532 ]])
```

Or to print all 4 keys and embedded tables, run:

```
for k, v in result.items():
    print(f'{k}:\n{v!r}')
```